# Django: filter by aggregate

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I am trying to filter by a value calculated using aggregates. Currently I am doing this:

```
max_val = some_queryset.aggregate(max_val=Max('some_prop'))['max_val']
some_queryset.filter(some_prop=max_val)
```

Is there a way I can use `max_val` to filter, all done in a single query?

Unfortunately I am using Django 1.4. and no, I cannot update it, it is simply not up to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the new field and compare with values from the aggregated field using an `F` expression:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

some_queryset.annotate(max_val=Max('some_prop')).filter(max_val=F('another_prop'))
```

Annotation and [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) exist in Django 1.4.

Answer (score -1):

I donot know if this works on django 1.4 but you need to use annotate if you need to further filter it.

`some_queryset.annotate(max_val=Max('some_prop')).filter(max_val=max_val)`

You may need to populate `max_val` from your aggregate query.

Comment: The right hand side is a variable the question seeks to eliminate.